# Getting the value of an option in a dropdown and using it in an if statement

Tags: java, selenium

I have a dropdown menu that has a bunch of dates. Each of these dates have a value attached to it in the form of `"yyyymm"`. What I want to do is take the date that is in the value attribute and compare it to the current month and year. The HTML looks like this:

```
<select name="selectPeriod">
    <option value="201511">Nov 2015</option>
    <option value="201510">Oct 2015</option>
    <option value="201509">Sept 2015</option>
```

Using an IF statement, I want to look at the value of the first option, and compare it to the the current date. I just need to check the first option, rather than cycling through the entire dropdown menu. My current set up looks like this:

```
int month=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int year =Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
String CurDate = String.valueOf(year+month);
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectedPeriod")));

   dropdown.selectByIndex(0);
   String ValDate = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("ValDate");
      if(valDate.equals(CurDate)){
         System.out.println("Worked: ");
          } else {System.out.println("Didnt work: ");
       }
```

the current code provides and `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` error, which I'm assuming is referring to the `String ValDate = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("ValDate")` portion of my code not being filled with an actual value.

I've only started working with Java and [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) the last couple days, so much of this has been trial and error. What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: Did you mean `.getAttribute("value");`? Also, what if you inspect the value of  `dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption()` - what is it equal to? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Well I didn't originally, but once I changed it to value, it fixed the issue with me getting the error. Unfortunately it looks as though the `If statement` is not working as it should. I took away the `+1` from  `int month=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1` in order to get the month of Nov, but the if statement prints out `Didnt work`.

Comment: @alecxe I discovered my issue with the if statement not working (Was adding the two `int` year and month together withing the string `CurDate`). If you want to make your comment an answer, I will give you the check mark.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Your example source code violates the important Java convention where a class name starts with initial cap (uppercase) while an instance starts with a lowercase letter. So `String curDate` rather than `String CurDate`, and likewise, `valDate` not `ValDate`.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 The [accepted Answer by alecxe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34407824/642706) correctly addresses your specific question. But there are other serious issues with your code. Answering here would be tangential, so I posted [a similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34408650/642706) with [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34408651/642706). You may find it interesting and helpful.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for commenting, your question/answer are very informative. I'll definitely be making the changes to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `option` values don't have the `ValDate` attribute - you've probably meant to get `value` attribute instead. Replace:

```
dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("ValDate");
```

with:

```
dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("value");
```