# How to get the first day of a month

Tags: android, kotlin, localdate

I am trying to get the first day of a month, when I pass July 2022, I want to get 1st July 2022 midnight.

This is what I tried

```
fun String.firstDayOfMonth(monthYearString: String, timeZoneId: ZoneId): LocalDate? {
var firstDayOfMonth: LocalDate? = null
try {
    val dateFormatterMonthAndYear: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM yyyy")
    val yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(monthYearString, dateFormatterMonthAndYear)
    //val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(monthYearString, dateFormatterMonthAndYear)
    firstDayOfMonth = yearMonth.atDay(1)
} catch (e:Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}


return firstDayOfMonth
```

}

I get an exception `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'July 2022' could not be parsed at index 3`

any suggestions please

thanks
R

Comment: I think I know what the issue was I should be using MMMM as it is July.

Answer (score 1):

if `"Jul 2022"` is passed

```
val dateFormatterMonthAndYear: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM yyyy")
val yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(monthYearString, dateFormatterMonthAndYear)
firstDayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(yearMonth.year, yearMonth.month, 1) //2022-06-01

firstDayOfMonth.dayOfWeek //WEDNESDAY
```

In YearMonth `"MMM"` means `"Jan"` not `"January"`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408650/generate-parse-year-month-values-in-text-from-java) for more info.